# Can the $g_i$ be chosen such that they are $C^{r+1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

(a) Prove that if $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $f(0) = 0$, then there exist $g_i: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n = x_ig_i(x)$

(b) Show that, if  $f(x_1, x_2, ...,x_n)$ is $C^{r+1}$ (i.e., r + 1 times continuously differentiable) and $f(0,...,0,x_{k+1},...,x_n) = 0$, then $f(x) = \sum_{1}^k = x_ig_i(x)$, where each $g_i$ is $C^r$. Can the $g_i$ be chosen such that they are $C^{r+1}$?

I was able to solve part (a) by letting $h_x(t)= f(tx)$ which implies that $f(x) = \int_0^1 = h'_x(t)dt$ and then using the Chain Rule. But I cannot for the life of me figure out part (b).

Can anyone help? I've been at this for a while now.

Comment: Riemann sums? You mean the chain rule? For the latter part of (b), it's pretty clear that if the $g_i$ are $C^{r+1}$, then $f$ will end up $C^{r+2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The same proof works for part (b), just breaking up the variable $x=(\underbrace{x_1,\dots,x_k}_u,\underbrace{x_{k+1},\dots,x_n}_v)$. Try using $h_x(t) = f(tu,v)$.